# How does scipy.optimize.fmin (Simplex) deal with parameters associated with different magnitudes?

Tags: python, scipy, simplex

I want to fit a 4-parameters (a,g,N and k) model to data by minimizing a chi-square loss function with a python implementation of the Simplex algorithm (scipy.optimize.fmin). 
Preliminary simulations suggest the following range for each parameter: a = [5, 50], g = [0.05, 1.5], N = [5, 200],and k = [0, 0.05].

Looks like the scipy.optimize.fmin function treats the parameters as if they were all in the same range (presumably [0, 1]). Should I rescale them?  Below is my code:

```
#determine starting point (x0) for each parameter
a = np.random.uniform(5,50)
g = np.random.uniform(0.05, 1.5)
N = np.random.uniform(5, 200)
k = np.random.uniform(0, 0.05)
x0 = np.array ([a, g, N, k]) #initial guess for SIMPLEX

xopt = fmin (chis, x0, maxiter=1000)#call Simplex
```

Comment: Is the `chis` function homemade ? if this is the case, i would rescale the objectives of minimization by making them relative instead of absolute. I mean working with variations rather than with differentials.

Comment: Absolutely, the chis function is homemade. I can provide the code if necessary. Could you be more specific? What do you mean by "working with variations?

Comment: What led you to come up with this question ? What results do you have when minimizing, for example ?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you want to minimize the following bi-variate function

```
def to_min1((x,y)):
    return abs(1e-15 - x) + abs(1e15 - y)
```

Even if this example is not realistic, it highlights the main point. For sure, `fmin` *may* not move in `x` (if `x0=0`), because it is already very close to zero.

So as to get objectives which have equal weights within the optimization program, one makes them in terms of variations rather than in terms of differentials (with arguments to numerators to avoid `ZeroDivisionError`):

```
def to_min2((x,y)):
    return abs(-1+x/1e-15) + abs(-1+y/1e15)
```

Note that this is an [`ftol`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) concern, since, by doing so, one wants its iterative recomputation to be equally weighted over all arguments.

What follows does not exactly answer to your question, but to the one:
*Does scipy.optimize.fmin (Simplex) deal with parameters associated with different magnitudes?*

Apparently no, since

```
>>> fmin(to_min1, (0,0))
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 1000000000000000.000000
         Iterations: 3
         Function evaluations: 11
array([ 0.,  0.])
```

while

```
>>> fmin(to_min2, (0,0))
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 1.000000
         Iterations: 118
         Function evaluations: 213
array([  1.00000000e-15,   8.98437500e-05])
```

For sure the `Optimization` did not `terminate successfully.`, and it could be done by increasing `fmin`'s `maxiter` argument, etc... but the two cases are clearly not managed the same way.